# localize many images in Xcode at once?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

I have this project that i need to add a translation to. I already know how to add localisation to single image files, but there are 200+ images with text on it in that project. Do i really have to click one file at a time, "get info", click "add localisation" enter the Language and click OK for every file?
When i select multiple images the languages and do those steps the new language is not added :-/

Please someone have a way to save me from insanity ;-)

Thanks!
S

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I do is create my localizable directories (en.lproj, fr_FR.lproj, etc) then I will drag all the localizable images into their respective directories, then add all the new images to the Xcode project. Xcode is smart enough to realize that the same image name exists in multiple .lproj directories

So, to reiterate:

1. Create localizable directories (you can use Get Info->Make File Localizable then add localizations for all desired locales)
2. Copy images for each locale into their respective directories
3. Add all the images to the xcode project

Comment: Best way so far. That does not help much with a finished project that needs to be localized later though. *sigh*

Comment: When I do this I get a "Multiple build commands for output file:" build warning for every localization. Xcode doesn't seems to be complaining that the files have the same name (which they should since they are localized).

Comment: Same issue. "Get Info->Make File Localizable" does not exist...
I need clarification on the answer.